# how to get user profile setting by id in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to PHP and MySQL. I'm developing school level project.
I'm trying to make user profile setting. please tell me where I'm wrong

**1: no id form home page
2: no id whenever I click on setting
3: when I try to give manual id and run it works fine..**

**Home page**

```
session_start();
$id= $_REQUEST['id']; 
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  users where id= '$id'");
$res = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
$id = $res['id'];

<a href="edit_profile.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">setting</a>
```

Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\Code\include\header.php on line 5

> Blockquote
>   URL getting no user id

http://localhost/code/edit_profile.php?id=

edit_profile

```
$id= $_REQUEST['id']; 
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  users where id= '$id'");
$res = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
$username= $res['username'];
```

Comment: you're not echoing the `$id` and use `isset()` for the array

Comment: well if id is blank then of course the query on edit_profile.php will fail

Comment: show us the full code and if and where the `href` is located in, and try GET instead of REQUEST

Comment: add `$id=42;` to top of home page, problem solved

Comment: i want get user id automatically ... not maual

Comment: ok great - but how could we know where it comes from? nothing in your code says `$id = XXXXXXXXXXXX`

Comment: you edited your question but that doesn't tell us if that is exactly how it's being used. You have php then the href right under it, so hard to help that way. @Dagon can probably guess it better than me. he's got something I don't.... ;-)

Comment: session_start();
 $id= $_REQUEST['id']; 
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  users where id= '$id'");
 $res = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
$username= $res['username'];

Comment: home page now same as edit profile ? the actual source of $id is still a mystery to me

Comment: cant understand actually.. need help how to get id

Answer (score -1):

To avoid error message you can to check your result before use:

*home.php*

```
session_start();

$id= isset($_REQUEST['id'])?$_REQUEST['id']:''; 
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  users where id= '$id'");
if ( $res = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) ) {
  $id = $res['id'];
}

<a href="edit_profile.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">setting</a>
```

Same thing for *edit_profile.php*

```
$id= isset($_REQUEST['id'])?$_REQUEST['id']:''; 
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  users where id= '$id'");
if ($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  $username= $res['username'];
} else {
  $username='';
}
```

But generally I would say you have to learn best practices with mysqli and PDO and rewrite your code (`mysql_*` functions are deprecated for a long time).

**UPDATE** According to some your comments you can get list of all profiles to edit on your homepage if you change your code:

```
//$id= isset($_REQUEST['id'])?$_REQUEST['id']:''; //on homepage usually you don't have any id yet
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  users ");
while ( $res = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) ) {
      echo '<p><a href="edit_profile.php?id='.$res['id'].'">Edit: '.$res['username'].' profile</a></p>' ;
}
```

Comment: Alex result like previous URL not getting id from user table http://localhost/code/edit_profile.php?id=